# Highchart multi color gradient

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, colors, gradient

I wanted to make a multi color gradient for a spiderweb chart, I have used the `linearGradient` feature on highcharts. I would like for the center to be red -> orange -> yellow -> green.

The `data` points that I would like corresponding with the color gradient are : red = 0 , orange = 1, yellow = 2, green = 3.

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/12/

I'm not quite sure how to manipulate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to play around with `radialGradient`, for example:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Planning',
  type: 'area',
  color: {
    radialGradient: {
      cx: 0.25,
      cy: 0.4,
      r: 0.5
    },
    stops: [
      [0.25, '#ff0000'],
      [0.5, '#ff8000'],
      [0.75, '#feff00'],
      [1, '#3eff00']
    ]
  },
  data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
  pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/13/

Comment: This is wonderful, I'll keep playing around with radialGradient.

Another question, in the demo you can see that the end points are multi colored along with the hover box border, also the text within the hover box.

How would it be possible to change the color of those?

Comment: Right! You can set color per point, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/14/

Comment: Great! How can I apply for the text in the hover box? Also when I hover over the points they change back to the multi color

Comment: I think it will be easier to use `fillColor` instead of `color`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/15/ Otherwise you need to change `point.marker.states.hover.color` and `tooltip.pointFormatter`.

Comment: You can also use `userSpaceOnUse` to use global coordinates, instead of `objectBoundingBox`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/18/ And `gradientUnits` explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits).